# Having two realm database in a project and merging it

Tags: ios, xamarin, realm

I have two type of users for my App, paid and free ones.
For free users I am not providing any backup of the data they create in my app. So this realm db instance(say db1) is not synced .
For Paid users I am proving backup and here I am using synced realm db(say db2).

Condition here is when user prefers to be a paid user. How can I sync the data which is available in the previous offline realm db? How can I merge this db1 in to db2?

Also, I am writing a big chuck of data in Db (video and images). I would prefer writing and reading asynchronously.
I tried writeAsync method it gives exception. Any tips for this would be appreciated.

Below code is throwing saying realm is accessed from wrong thread.

```
public async Task InsertItemInDB(Post model)
        {
            try
            {
                //realm.Write(() =>
                //   {

                //     realm.Add(model);

                //   });
                var realm = Realm.GetInstance(Config);
                await realm.WriteAsync( (Realm obj) => {


                    realm.Add(model, true);
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex){

                Console.WriteLine("problem writing to DB" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1) You could export/import from each Realm db using `Json` each you can not have both db open at the same time... 2) `writing a big chuck of data`... beware of the 16MB per byte array limitation, personally I totally avoid storing binary assets within Realm as the memory requirements become a large issue, especially on iOS, as far as the `Exception` that you are getting, we could need the code that is throwing the exception and the actual exception.

Comment: Yeah because of 16 Mb limitation , i had to limit video length to 7 sec .
My client is sure about media to be in Db nothing else i could say to convince him other wise .
He wants backup of all data ,You got suggestions?

Comment: You could just use **`Realm's Mobile Platform`** to sync the user database... simple and prebuilt option. Otherwise you are going to have to serialize the data in some way and upload that to your server and store it there by some type of user id and add the ability to download an restore it in the db.....

Comment: But still i cant have a video bigger than 16 Mb right ?

Comment: Correct, unless you slice them into segments smaller then 16MB each and stitch them together external to Realm for playback... but again, personally, storing large data like that in Realm is a bad idea, we have a Realm-based app that is ***very*** large that all binary *assets* are stored/cached externally. Even then, due to the size of the Realm database it will only open on iPad Pro 4GB models and we have to be very careful otherwise the user is left with a Realm db that is corrupt. Watch your DB size very carefully...

Comment: i mean to tackle this issue , i have put limitation of 7 sec video which is like ,14 mb and one image is like 1 mb max .

i am gonna limit the DB size to 2 Gb after that i will start deleting the stuff . what you say?

Comment: It is really hard to recommend a solution with limited knowledge of the total project, but prototyping and using a strict MVVM/VIPER architecture so you have the option to substitute a different storage container and/or splitting your data models between an object store and file-based cache and providing different sync methods for your user data would be a starting point if I was working on it...

Comment: Its MVC though !

Comment: iOS ***Massive*** View Controller.... ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139074/discussion-between-saket-kumar-and-sushihangover).

Comment: @Sushi- Added the code which is throwing exception , looking forward to know the problem

Answer (score 2):

When you start a `WriteAsync` block, you have to use the `Realm` instance that is passed into lamb block otherwise you will get an invalid thread exception.

Your code should be:

```
await realm.WriteAsync( (Realm obj) => {
    // Use the Realm instance that was passed in, i.e. `Realm obj`
    obj.Add(model, true);
});
```

Comment: can u tell me , diff between , obj.Add(model,true) & obj.Add(model,false)
meanwhile i am trying this one

Comment: For objects where you have specified a [PrimaryKey], you can pass in update: true in realm.Add to add the passed in object or update the existing one : https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#updating-objects

Comment: it should be false when adding 1st time then ! Ok